# data type convertion error "Run Time Error 3421

Tags: ms-access-2010

This is the code that I am using to insert data do a table. if the store field is null I am having that error. there is a way to fix this with out a validation?

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
If IsNull(Me.txtstore) Then
MsgBox "Please enter Store Number"
Exit Sub
Else
'add data to the table
Dim db As Database
Dim rec As Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from Stores")
rec.AddNew
rec("Stores") = Me.txtstore
rec("Tier") = Me.cbotier
rec("Company") = Me.cbocompany
rec("Market") = Me.cbomarket
rec("Region") = Me.cboregion
rec("District Manager") = Me.cbodistrictmanger
rec("Market Manager") = Me.cbomarketmanager

rec.Update

Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
'refresh sub form
frmStoressub.Requery

MsgBox "Records updated", , "Message"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: But you do check for Null: `If IsNull(Me.txtstore) Then` so where is the error? If you mean some fields of Stores cannot accept Null values, adjust that in table design.